# Python 3 cx_Freeze 5.0.2 Import Error: No module named 'idna'

Tags: python, importerror, cx-freeze, python-module

I have attempted to use the setup.py script from [this site](https://regilanj.wordpress.com/2017/06/07/py-to-exe-in-python-3-6-1/) to turn my .py script into a executable file. The attempts haven't been successful due to an error saying:

```
ImportError: No module named 'idna'
```

Here is the setup.py script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = None


executables = [Executable("my first prog.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },

}

setup(
    name = "<any name>",
    options = options,
    version = "<any number>",
    description = '<any description>',
    executables = executables
)
```

Here are the error lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 26, in <module>
  executables = executables
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 349, in setup
  distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
  self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 219, in run
  freezer.Freeze()
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 621, in Freeze
  self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 340, in _GetModuleFinder
  finder.IncludePackage(name)
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 653, in IncludePackage
  module = self._ImportModule(name, deferredImports)
File "C:\Users\rayxu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 350, in _ImportModule
  raise ImportError("No module named %r" % name)
ImportError: No module named 'idna'
```

Any ideas about what's wrong? I'm running python 3.6.2 on my computer.

Comment: add this import to your script and try `import encodings.idna`

Comment: I did add it and it still does not work.